# How did the continue statement worked here?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, continue

I understand that "continue" makes the program jump back to the loop.

Here for example:

```
while True:
   print('Who are you?')
   name = input()
   if name != 'Joe':
       continue
   print('Hello, Joe')
```

So if I type any name other than joe, the continue statement skips it and jumps back to the loop because the condition `"if"` is true, but if it's false, the programs continues to the last line `print('Hello, Joe')`

However here in this code I did not understand how the continue statement worked:

```
for num in range(2, 10):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Found an even number", num)
        continue
    print("Found a number", num)
```

Under what condition the continue statement "skipped" and jumped back to the loop? It seems it behaved more like the else statement.

Comment: You're right that it's sort of used like an `else`. As far as "what condition", it's given in the code: `if num % 2 == 0`. If the number is even, then the final print statement is not executed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> Under what condition the continue statement "skipped" and jumped back to the loop?

The `if` condition looks for an even number. If the number is even, then, as you said, it would print `"Found an even number"`, and continue on in the `for` loop.

You are therefore also correct that code written:

```
for num in range(2, 10):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Found an even number", num)
    else:
        print("Found a number", num)
```

Would yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The continue statement doesn't 'jump back' in a for loop, it just goes to the next iteration.
In the example, after the continue statement, we move onto the next element (uneven number)

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is the function of the `%` operator in the if statement: `if num % 2 == 0`. Which should **not be confused** with the % marker used for string formatting.

`num1 % num2` yields the remainder of the integer division operation `num1/num2`. This is often called the **modulo** operation.

If the number is even like 40 then 40%2 equals 0:

```py
>>> foo = 40
>>> print(foo%2)
0
```

If the number is odd like 17 then 17%2 equals 1

```
>>> foo = 17
>>> print(foo%2)
1
```

Therefore the `num%2` operation can be used to detect of `num` is even or odd by checking if the result of this operation is equal to 0 or not as in:

```
if num%2 == 0:
 print('the number is even')
```